# IPC between Firefox extension and COM component

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, ipc, xpcom

I need to make a synchronous call between a *JavaScript XPCOM component* and a *COM component* (native WIN32 process).

I know, options are:
1) Open up sockets and use TCP/IP
2) Have an NPAPI plugin, and load the plugin in the extensions XUL
3) Use Ctypes

Is there any other better way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also the possibility to have an executable in your extension and call it via `nsIProcess` - but that's one-way communication only. Not sure whether it is "better", depends on what your problem with ctypes is.

Answer (score 0):

nsIProcess does not support IPC. Here is a project in which developers try to develop new interface:

[http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/User:Jamesboston](http://zenit.senecac.on.ca/wiki/index.php/User%3aJamesboston)